# I need to store a car's make and model. Should I have car brands/models be database tables, or should I just hardcode them as field choices?

Tags: django

I'm writing an application where users put in information about their cars. Part of what I need to do is have a dropdown for the fields of car brand and car model. At first, I was going to hardcode this into tuples and then use the `choices` field on a `models.CharField`. But then I realized that this could take an unreasonable amount of time, and I would undoubtably miss a few models. Instead of hardcoding, I'm thinking of making a `CarBrand` and `CarModel` table, and then adding different brands and models via the admin site. Which approach is better?

Comment: They should be database tables if the car brands/models are going to change often, or if there are a lot of them. Hardcoding as field choices is only suitable for cases where the choices themselves are not going to change much (e.g. `citizen`, `permanent resident`, `foreigner`; `male`, `female`, etc.)

Comment: As a bonus `tuple( CarMake.objects.all().values_list('code','human_name'))` is directly suitable for use as a choices specifier (a tuple of 2-tuples).